# NAND gate with inverted input

Tags: boolean-logic, demorgans-law

If I were to take the expression:

```
(A + B + C + D + E)
```

And use de morgan's law to transform it to:

```
(!A!B!C!D!E)!
```

Would I have to invert each bit before put it into a NAND gate? Is there a simpler way?

EDIT: there is no short cut. You have to do (!A!B!C!D!E)!

Comment: have you found any other answer ???

Comment: Unfortunately, the design you offered is incorrect

Comment: can you say what is that

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to get invert for each inputs,i think invert needs like this expression :)

Eg: `(A' + B' + C' + D' + E')`

i'm not remember properly,but hope this will be helped to you

[image]